# About the Toast command

Tags: java, android

I want to know what 'this' means in the below Toast command:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "msg" ,Toast.Length_long ).show();
```

If possible could you please explain the whole command.

Comment: Just read: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#java . If you do not know what a context is then you need to read some books/tutorials about it first.

Comment: `Toast` is an **object**, not a **command**. You lack the fundamentals of OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you use construct `SomeClass.this` that means that you are referring to the specific (frequently 'outer' class). In example you can have a code like:

```
class Apple { 

void outherMethod() {
}

class AppleType {

    void innerMethod(){}
        void method(){ 
            Apple.this.outerMethod();
        this.innerMethod();
    }
 }
 }
```

Additionally, in this specific case on Android it means that you are using the activity's Context which is provided via MainActivity class.

So the whole command should be read as:

- Create Toast widget inside context provided by MainActivity
- It should display some text: "msg"
- It should be visible for specific time defined by the constant: Toast.Length_long
- finally, via show() method display it on device.

Answer (score 0):

'this' means itself.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "msg" ,Toast.Length_long ).show();
```

Call the toast method, and the required parameters are 'context', 'toast message' and 'toast duration'.

Finally .show() means make toast to show.

Comment: whether "this" means that the mainactivity is contained within itself

Comment: @AravindD MainActivity.this means MainActivity instance itself. So, the mainactivity.this gets context of activity(in this case - mainactivity)

Answer (score 0):

its clear and you can use it like this

```
Toast toast =Toast.makeText(this, "msg", duration);
toast.show();
```

this: context
"msg": your message
duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG
and you can change position by setting gravity

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
```

this will show toast center screen